# How can i store all the values of the list box (select) to an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, list, select

```
<select name = "lstTerminals" size = "5" id="lstTerminals"style="width:200px;"> 
                    <option value="C172"> >C172</option>
                    <option value="B737">B737</option>
                    <option value="D483">D483</option>
    </select> <br/> <br/>
```

How can I get all the values inside of this list and store it into an array and use all these data onto another php script? After all that, how can I call these values in another php script? Would anyone please me with this? I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: How familiar with Ajax are you?

Comment: not so  much, is this also possible with javascript?

Comment: The best way I can think of doing it IS with javascript. With Ajax, actually. This is assuming that this select dropdown is in a page that you can modify (add Javascript code etc), of course.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky with a client-side solution. Assuming you have a php-script generating the select in the question you should do this server-side.

If the values are on a user page your best bets are

1. A session variable.
2. A hidden form field.

For 1. Set the value of `$_SESSION['lstTerminalValues']` to an array with the values. Do this when you create the original select.

For 2. you'd have something like

```
<input type="hidden" name="lstTerminalValues" value="C172,B737,D483"/>
```

then recreate the array with
`$optionsArray = explode(',', $_QUERY['lstTerminalValues']);`.